# the way to use setState with object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, {useState} from "react";



const SideListItem = () => {

    const [showItem, setShowItem] = useState([
        {id: "List A", clicked: true},
        {id: "List B", clicked: true},
        {id: "List C", clicked: true},
    ]);
    

    const clickList = () => {
        const value = showItem[0].clicked;
        setShowItem(() => {
            const boolValue = value? false: value === true;
            return boolValue;
        });

        

        return console.log(value);
                
    };
```

I want to make the next process below.

1. when I click a button, the value of state is chaged.

   => if it is "true", then it changed in "false". And if "false", then "true".

But, my code didn't work... When I used state with number, string, boolean, It worked.

Is there a way to use state with object?

Thank you in advance!

I tried this code.

const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
const clickList = () => setClicked(!clicked);

But, I want to use state with object.

Comment: Which value? You have 3 booleans in the state

Comment: the first one! And every booleans, if possible....^^

Comment: `setShowItem(array => array.map(obj => ({ ...obj, clicked: !obj.clicked })))`

Comment: Thank you! you are expert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this and add more statements if needed:

```
const clickList = () => {
    setShowItem(prevState => {
        return prevState.map(item => {
            if (item.id === "List A") {
                return {...item, clicked: !item.clicked};
            }
            return item;
        });
    });
};
```

But it's better to get the id as param like this:

```
const clickList = (id) => {
    setShowItem(prevState => {
        return prevState.map(item => {
            if (item.id === id) {
                return {...item, clicked: !item.clicked};
            }
            return item;
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you! I need more study...! you helped me very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle  it in this way :

```
  const clickList = () => {
    setShowItem(prevState => {prevState.map(item=>({...item,clicked:!item.clicked})));
  };
```

Comment: your welcome, if it's what you were looking for , please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the previous state of the array to one where the `clicked` property of the clicked item is toggled. Since you didn't provide any html I added some example html, swap it out for your own markup and use the onClick event as such:

```js
const { useCallback, useState } = React;

const SideListItem = () => {
    const [showItem, setShowItem] = useState([
        {id: "List A", clicked: true},
        {id: "List B", clicked: true},
        {id: "List C", clicked: true},
    ]);
    
    const handleClick = useCallback(id => {
      setShowItem(p => p.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            clicked: !item.clicked
          }
        }
        return item;
      }));
    }, []);
    
    return showItem.map(item =>
      <div key={item.id} onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}>
        Clicked: {item.clicked ? "yes" : "no"}
      </div>
    );
 }

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <SideListItem />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```